# How is character encoding specified in a multipart/form-data HTTP POST request?

Tags: html, post, utf-8, multipartform-data

The HTML 5 specification describes an [algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#multipart-form-data) for selecting the character encoding to be used in a multi-part form submission (e.g. UTF-8). However, it is not clear how the selected encoding should be relayed to the server so that the content can be properly decoded on the receiving end.

Often, character encodings are represented by appending a "charset" parameter to the value of the `Content-Type` request header. However, this parameter does not appear to be defined for the `multipart/form-data` MIME type:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-8

Each part in a multipart form submission may provide its own `Content-Type` header; however, RFC 7578 notes that "in practice, many widely deployed implementations do not supply a charset parameter in each part, but rather, they rely on the notion of a 'default charset' for a multipart/form-data instance".

RFC 7578 goes on to suggest that a hidden "_charset_" form field can be used for this purpose. However, neither Safari (9.1) nor Chrome (51) appear to populate this field, nor do they provide any per-part encoding information.

I've looked at the request headers produced by both browsers and I don't see any obvious character encoding information. Does anyone know how the browsers are conveying this information to the server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HTML 5 uses RFC 2388 (obsoleted by RFC 7578), however HTML 5 *explicitly* removes the `Content-Type` header from non-file fields, while the RFCs do not:

> The parts of the generated multipart/form-data resource that correspond to non-file fields must not have a `Content-Type` header specified. Their names and values must be encoded using the character encoding selected above (field names in particular do not get converted to a 7-bit safe encoding as suggested in RFC 2388).

The RFCs are designed to allow `multipart/form-data` to be usable in other contexts besides just HTML (though that is its most common use).  In those other contexts, `Content-Type` is allowed.  Just not in HTML 5 (but is allowed in HTML 4).

Without a `Content-Type` header, the hidden `_charset_` form field, if present, is the only way an HTML 5 `<form>` submitter can *explicitly* state which charset is used.

Per the HTML 5 algorithm spec that you linked to, the chosen charset MUST be selected from the `<form>` element's `accept-charset` attribute if present, otherwise be the charset used by the HTML itself if it is ASCII-compatible, otherwise be UTF-8.  This is explicitly stated in the algorithm spec, as well as in RFC 7578 Section 5.1.2 when referring to HTML 5.

So, there really is no need for the charset to be *explicitly* stated by a web browser since the receiver of the form submission should know which charset(s) to expect by virtue of how the `<form>` was created, and thus can check for those charset(s) while parsing the submission.  If the receiver wants to know the *specific* charset used, it needs to include a hidden `_charset_` field in the `<form>`.

Comment: "There really is no need for the charset to be explicitly stated by a web browser since the receiver of the form submission should know which charset(s) to expect by virtue of how the <form> was created." This is effectively the basis of my question. How would the server actually know how the form was created? The form declaration itself is not submitted to the server - only the data entered into the form. How is the value of the `accept-charset` attribute propagated to the server, if not in the hidden `_charset_` parameter?

Comment: @GregBrown without `_charset_`, the writer of the HTML and the writer of the form receiver (if they are not the same) would need to coordinate with each other on the server side. `accept-charset` should only contain charsets the receiver is prepared to process. The webserver should be configured to know what charset the HTML is served as. There are only two ways a web browser can pass a charset in a form submission, `Content-Type` and `_charset_`, but HTML 5 forbids `Content-Type`.

Comment: OK. This is the conclusion that I came to as well. Thank you for the detailed response.